# Nextjs redirect not working after running POST request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a button that submits a form. That submit function runs a post request to my api route and in the api route, I insert a row in my database. I need to redirect the user to `/` when its all done. But for some reason `return redirect("/")` just doesn't work. My tab just stays on loading and nothing happens.

Submit function:

```js
const handleSubmit = async () => {;
        try {
            const res = await fetch("/api/saveRecipe", {
                method: "POST", 
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    title: title,
                    time: time,
                    time_unit: timeUnit,
                    serves: serves,
                    ingredients: ingredients,
                    instructions: instructions,
                }),
            });
      
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message || e.description);
        }
    };
```

`api/saveRecipe/route.js`

```js
import { createRouteHandlerClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
export async function POST(req) {
    const supabase = createRouteHandlerClient({ cookies });
    try {
        const data = await req.json();
        const { recipe, error } = await supabase.from("Recipes").insert([data]);
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.description || error.message);
    }

    return redirect("/");
}
```

**The row gets added to the database successfully so its not a problem with the api calls. And this exact redirect line was used in another route and it works fine so idk what's going on**

Comment: Good to know: redirect does not require you to use `return redirect()`
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect#example

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same problem.

Temporarily solving it with:
window.location.replace('/dashboard')

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and I solved it by returning **return NextResponse.redirect(redirectUrl)** in the route handler instead of using the **redirect** function from 'next/navigation'

You should be able to do something like this

```
import { createRouteHandlerClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
export async function POST(req) {
    const supabase = createRouteHandlerClient({ cookies });
    try {
        const data = await req.json();
        const { recipe, error } = await supabase.from("Recipes").insert([data]);
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.description || error.message);
    }

    return NextResponse.redirect("/")
}
```